# PPTP VPN SERVER

Tags: 11.04, server, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I have followed [This guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56559/how-do-i-set-up-a-pptp-vpn-on-my-own-ubuntu-server) and also the documentation for pptp vpn and my vpn connects. It even allows me to go on the web and search it. However, when I go to cmyip.com; it displays my personal ip (as if the vpn is not connected) I have other vpns (i used ddwrt pptp) and it displays the ip address of the vpn server im connected to? 
Let me know how i can fix this.

Same issue as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104404/pptp-server-clients-still-have-original-ip) and it remains un answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering. The above guides that I mentioned worked.

The problem was that I was using my own ip script using the php guest ip call on the same machine that was running my vpn. The address it was returning was my real address, (at home) and not the masked address (the server) but thats because the server already knew my home address in its ip tables.

So, follow the guides and it will work for you as well.

Comment: I also want to include my tutorial https://www.linuxclever.com/2017/05/31/how-to-setup-a-pptp-vpn-server/