# VPN server on ubuntu enabling NAT problem! please help

Tags: 12.04, networking, vpn, iptables, pptpd

Hi I am trying to Create a vpn server on a vps which is running ubuntu percise 12.04. I have already installed pptpd and I have enabled ip forwarding but when I try to enable NAT with this command :

```
sudo -i iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $OUTIF --jump MASQUERADE
```

that I'm using from [This guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56559/how-do-i-set-up-a-pptp-vpn-on-my-own-ubuntu-server)
I get this error : iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

I have tried other guides as well and everytime I'm stuck on this issue one way or another . Does anybody know what's wrong? can you guide towards any resources to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The command works for me. However, and since I never defined `$OUTIF`, I just entered what it is. I am saying I did this:

```
sudo -i iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 --jump MASQUERADE
```