# How to access blocked site?

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access Facebook and other forbidden websites in China?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56508/how-to-access-facebook-and-other-forbidden-websites-in-china)

In China facebook,youtube,twitter and some more sites are blocked ..so how can we access this sites ? I have tried tor but I don't know how to use it....so please if someone give me full instruction it would be appreciated ...Please guys help me I am a new ubuntu user .

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://askubuntu.com/q/56508/10698

Answer (score 2):

A TOR guide. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor

Or you can try this http://www.52ap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by using PROXY servers. You might find some useful information here

http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/unblock-and-access-youtube-from-china.html