# Simple and easy way to bypass blocked sites

Tags: proxy, squid

My ISP blocks a lot of websites so I need an easy way to bypass it. I use a proxy to bypass it.

What if I use my own squid server will it bypass my ISP block sites?  I need an easy and simple way to bypass blocked websites.

For DNS server I have tried OpenDNS and Google DNS. Now I'm using my own DNS server.

As for Tor, I have used it, it work fine at bypassing the block but not for playing YouTube or Flash videos. As tor using Arora browser, maybe that's why its not playing videos.

Comment: i have downloaded the full tor patched with include browser in it as arora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how your ISP blocks websites.

In the simplest case, ISP's DNS server only returns wrong answers. Simply writing `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (that's [google's public DNS server](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/), you can also use alternatives such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) (`208.67.222.222`) or [others](http://www.tech-faq.com/public-dns-servers.html), or your own DNS resolver) to `/etc/resolv.conf` will solve that.

If the ISP blocks traffic to certain IPs, you need to route through at least one other node, for example with an HTTP proxy (such as squid), SOCKS proxy, [VPN](https://askubuntu.com/q/35647/6969), or an anonymization network such as [Tor](http://torproject.org/). The proxy must be installed in a censorship-free location; installing squid on your local computer will not change anything.

If the ISP blocks by keywords (i.e. uses Deep Packet Inspection), you can avoid those either with a VPN or an anonymization network, or with encrypted (e.g. HTTP**S**) connections.

Comment: Did changing the DNS server help? Regular Flash videos such as most youtube videos should simply use the proxy server as well. Since I'm personally very interested in censorship, and may be able to offer better debugging in a chat, I'd greatly appreciate a chat via Jabber/Google Talk/icq/facebook or so. You can find my addresses [on my homepage](http://phihag.de/).

Comment: yes i did all , mostly i use opendns but now i m using my own dns server , let me update more

Comment: The Tor browser bundle blocks plugins for privacy reasons by default. You can try to use HTML5 video by opting in at http://youtube.com/html5 . As I wrote above, I'd love to discuss this in chat. Can I reach you via an instant messaging/chat service?

Comment: yes sure onezero1983 on yahoo messenger

Answer (score 3):

VPN software can be used for bypassing such restrictions as it fully encrypts the traffic between your server and your machine. I've written instructions for setting up the server and client in [How do I setup OpenVPN so I can securely use the internet from an unsecured hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35647/6969)

Comment: a very good detail i will look at it soon

Answer (score 1):

Here are instructions on how to use [Google DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html).  If you scroll down the page you will find instructions on implementing the change with Linux.

You aren't limited to Google DNS, you can use [OpenDNS](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/how-to-switch-to-opendns-in-ubuntu-for-faster-browsing/) which is also popular.