# problems with openvpn

Tags: 12.10, openvpn

When I am  trying to install `Openvpn` on Ubuntu 12.10 I get only problems.
The config files are all empty and I only get error.

When I have installed it for first time it was not empty config files. but i did something wrong so I had to `apt-get purge openvpn` and `rm -rf /etc/openvpn/` . 
after that I have installed it again, then the real problems started. I can't finish the guide.

I have used the ubuntuguide instructions for installing[OpenVPN_server](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/OpenVPN_server) and when I come to Edit `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`: its nothing in there. What can I do?

Comment: Hugely minor point but don't you mean `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` ? I seem to think the `/` in front is important

Comment: that was a type error here ;) but thanks for putting that out. and the /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars is all empty too

Comment: Added that to my suggested edit then, I didn't want to edit it in case that was actually that was your problem

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/openvpn/` is empty by default (ok, except for `update-resolv-conf`). The `server.conf` file is copied from `/usr/share`. From that page:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz /etc/openvpn/
sudo gzip -d /etc/openvpn/server.conf.gz
```

Depending on your goals, this guide may also be of interest to you:

- [How do I setup OpenVPN so I can securely use the internet from an unsecured hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35647/6969)