# Is it possible to configure openvpn in ubuntu according configuration files relevant to windows?

Tags: configuration, openvpn, tunnel

I am using openvpn in windows and have the configuration files as well. Unfortunately the service provider doesn't have any guide or configuration files for Linux users. Is it possible to use windows configuration files to configure openvpn certification in ubuntu?
The configuration files type for windows is "visz".

Answer (score 0):

According to [SparkLabs.com >> Support](http://www.sparklabs.com/support/exporting_and_distributing_con/) the **.visz** file is actually a compressed **.visc** file. This site also shows the contents of that file.

You will likely need to configure your OpenVPN (on Ubuntu) to match the settings in this file.

[OpenVPN.net >> How To](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html)

---

Also look at:

[AskUbuntu >> How do I setup OpenVPN so I can securely use the internet from an unsecured hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35647/how-do-i-setup-openvpn-so-i-can-securely-use-the-internet-from-an-unsecured-hots)