# file permissions for openvpn setup

Tags: permissions, files, openvpn

I can't find what permissions I should give to certificates and to the folder.

I am importing the files from kde network manager.

If I give 400 or 640 permissions to /etc/openvpn ,then , from the network manager I can't open the folder openvpn in order to import the necessary files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not change the directory and you do (/should) not need to change the directory itself. `/etc/openvpn` needs to be something like 775 (rwxrwxr-x).

The permisions 400 (=readonly) are for the cert files. This explains it: [How do I setup OpenVPN so I can securely use the internet from an unsecured hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35647/how-do-i-setup-openvpn-so-i-can-securely-use-the-internet-from-an-unsecured-hots)

And do not forget: changes to `/etc/` need `sudo`.

Comment: :I checked that link but for example fro ca.crt it has permission 400.But with that permission I can't open the folder in order to import this file

Comment: :I should use sudo and not su first..

Comment: that too :D glad you got it fixed @George ;)