# Where does my installed file reside

Tags: command-line, sudo

When I do

> `sudo apt-get install openvpn`

... it does not install the file rather it downloads a file and stores some where . Now how can I find where the file has reside.

Comment: Did you try `sudo whereis openvpn`?

Comment: @deepesh: Plese provide us more details on your problem like what is happening while you are running **openvpn** from command line and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @oldfred: **sudo** is not needed while running `whereis`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have installed the [openvpn](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openvpn)[image: Install openvpn] package, you need to configure it accordingly. (for other readers, the files inside an *installed* package can be listed with `dpkg -L openvpn`.)

I can recommend you to use Network Manager which has an OpenVPN plugin. There you can put the certificates, host, etc. of your VPN provider. If you have none and want to setup the server and client, have a look at [How do I setup OpenVPN so I can securely use the internet from an unsecured hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35647/6969) (for example).

Comment: @karel I have no idea what is the problem, there are generic debugging steps she/he could take though. In the future you can also mail me at peter@lekensteyn.nl (flag this as obsolete so it can be removed)