# OpenVPN riddling syslog with errors, but otherwise seems to work flawlessly

Tags: networking, configuration, systemd, openvpn, syslog

Yesterday I configured OpenVPN on a Ubuntu 18.04 server which seems to work. I can connect no problem and "systemctl status openvpn" gives me green. However, my syslog is being riddled with errors which seem to relate to a different service than openvpn.service. I am kind of unsettled by this since the server goes into use tomorrow and the only way to get access then is via openvpn.

Here is the syslog:

> Jun 22 15:30:41 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Main process e xited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> Jun 22 15:30:41 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Failed with re sult 'exit-code'.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:41 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to mult i-user.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Service hold-o ff time over, scheduling restart.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Scheduled rest art job, restart counter is at 146.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to multi-user.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to multi-user. ..
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost ovpn-multi-user[3046]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/multi-user.conf
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost ovpn-multi-user[3046]: Use --help for more information .
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Main process e xited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Failed with re sult 'exit-code'.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:47 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to mult i-user.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:52 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Service hold-o ff time over, scheduling restart.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:52 localhost systemd[1]: openvpn@multi-user.service: Scheduled rest art job, restart counter is at 147.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:52 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to multi-user.
>
> Jun 22 15:30:52 localhost systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to multi-user.

Comment: Also asked on Unix.SE at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451340/openvpn-riddling-syslog-with-errors-but-otherwise-seems-to-work-flawlessly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I setup OpenVPN so I can securely use the internet from an unsecured hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35647/how-do-i-setup-openvpn-so-i-can-securely-use-the-internet-from-an-unsecured-hots)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the suggested post does not include an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by disabling openvpn@.service (deprecated), removing all configuration files from the OpenVPN root sir and moving them to the server dir, as well as activating the respective openvpn-server@config.service.